# Не могу понять как сделать остальную часть прямоугольника XD

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout << "Введите высоту а: ";
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Введите ширину b: ";
    int b;
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Введите символ: ";
    char s;
    cin >> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cout << s << endl ;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        cout << s;
        cout << " ";
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Может, как-нибудь так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < b; n++) {
        cout << s << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Выводим строку `s` столько раз, сколько указано в ширине. В конце строки, соответственно, перенос, а потом всё снова.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");


    /*Вывести на экран прямоугольник с заданными сторонами и заданным символом.
   Пользователь задает размеры сторон прямоугольника и символ вывода прямоугольника*/
    cout << "Введите сторону А: ";
    int w;
    cin >> w;

    cout << "Введите сторону B: ";
    int h;
    cin >> h;

    cout << "Введите символ с которым нужно нарисовать треугольник: ";
    char q;
    cin >> q;

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        cout << q;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < h - 2; i++) {
        cout << q;
        for (int j = 0; j < w - 2; j++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << q << "\n";

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        cout << q;
    }

}

//Я сделал. Спасибо)
```